# No control identifiers using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a problem with `print_control_identifiers()` using pywinauto.

I start my test by opening test app.

```
window1 = Application(backend="uia")
window1.start("C:/Program Files (x86)/.../App.exe")
window1.Dialog.print_control_identifiers()
window1.Dialog.Run.click()
```

This is ok, I have output with all elements in this dialog - all buttons, boxes, labels etc.
After `click()` my dialog disappears and i need to connect to new window, so:

```
window2 = Application().connect(title="new-window")
window2.AppDialog.print_control_identifiers()
```

And there is my problem: output not contains any elements, just simple:

```
HwndWrapper[App.exe;App;c002ffc1-d144-4cd1-8ab0-afe5031cb9ea] - 'new-window'    (L-8, T-8, R1928, B1058)
['new-window', 'HwndWrapper[App.exe;c002ffc1-d144-4cd1-8ab0-afe5031cb9ea]', 'new-windowHwndWrapper[App.exe;c002ffc1-d144-4cd1-8ab0-afe5031cb9ea]']
child_window(title="new-window", class_name="HwndWrapper[App.exe;c002ffc1-d144-4cd1-8ab0-afe5031cb9ea]")
```

How to print all control identifiers of this new window?

Whatever I try to find, eg. `window2.AppDialog.Login.click()` i have `pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to use `backend="uia"` for Application object in this line:

```
window2 = Application().connect(title="new-window")
```

It should look so:

```
window2 = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="new-window")
```

If the first window spawns a child process, you have to connect to this process which contains new window. We have plans to implement child process detection by Application object in the future. Now it should be handled manually.

Comment: Add ```backend="uia"``` didn't help. Now I have error: ```pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'new-window', 'backend': 'uia', 'visible_only': False}```

Comment: Call window2.windows() and print .window_text() for each of the returned top windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
    pid= application.process_from_module('toolName.exe')
    app= Application(backend="uia").connect(process=pid)
    handle = app.window(title_re="new-windowName")
    handle.print_control_identifiers()
```

Or just use Inspect.exe to get all the details if you dont need print it explicitly.
Inspect.exe can get you all the details of any element you focus on..